# Защита от ошибок в bot handler [telebot]

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу бота, у одной из функций, есть `call.data`, которая всегда состоит из строки `'basket_xxx'`, только вместо `xxx`, число. В одном из хендлеров, я принимаю именно такую `call.data` и обрабатываю, но бывает, что бот получает ошибку, если при запуске не находит нужный хендлер.

Вот мой код:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: (call.data).split('_')[1] in map(str, range(101, int((list(items.keys()))[-1]) )))
```

Я хочу в этом заголовке обрабатывать запрос, с помощью `try: except:`, например:

```
try: (call.data).split('_')[1] in map(str, range(101, int((list(items.keys()))[-1])
except: print(123)
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боже. Замените это

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: (call.data).split('_')[1] in map(str, range(101, int((list(items.keys()))[-1]) )))
```

На это

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("basket_"))
```

И вам не нужны никакие try/except

Comment: Большое вам спасибо.